# OpenSSL Blocking Socket Bio Read Write simultaneously?

Tags: openssl

If I use Socket BIO with socket in blocking mode. Can I have two threads, one waiting on SSL_Read call - for peer to send data, and other thread calling SSL_Write - when needed to send data?

Comment: It does not look safe, in case renegotiation are triggered, SSL_write may post read on socket